# How can I get the ng2 “this” context?

Tags: angularjs

"treeSettings" will passed to a jquery context and it will call "addHoverDom" method defined in same ts script.

In "addHoverDom" method, "this" object is not ng2 context, but a jquery function scope, how can I get the ng2 this context in a jquery native method? Thanks.

```
  this.treeSettings = {
    view: {
      addHoverDom: this.addHoverDom,
      removeHoverDom: this.removeHoverDom,
      selectedMulti: false
    },
  }

  addHoverDom(treeId, treeNode) {
    console.log('===', this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arrow function for callback so you don't loose the expected context of this:

```
this.treeSettings = {
    view: {
        addHoverDom: this.addHoverDom,
        removeHoverDom: this.removeHoverDom,
        selectedMulti: false
    },
}
addHoverDom = (treeId, treeNode) => {
    console.log('===', this);
}
```